#  add text to the end of a line

Tags: c, file-io, split

I am working on a file. I want to take each line and split after the space.
For example if line1 has: today is monday I want to have today, is, monday separatly in order to work on them

Here is my code so far:

```
FILE *file = fopen ( "file1", "r" );

            if ((file != NULL ))
            {
                char line [ 128 ]; 
                while( ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ))
                {
                //tokenize the line based on space

                ??

                }
how to add text at the end of the line? i mean i have **today is monday** and i want to add for example **Yupppy** at the end of today is monday line.

            fclose ( file );

            }
```

Comment: can you please post an example?thx

Comment: i also need to add programatically at the end of each line a new work. Can you help me with that too?thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To tokenize a string you can use [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)
Check the example in the link I post, just change the separator to space:

( code from the example linked )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>




int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course it should be noted that `strtok` is not reentrant and `strtok_r` should be used instead when available (or even `strsep` which I think is cleaner).

Comment: i am working in c. Thx. And how to add the word at the end of a char[]?

Comment: @justAngela you should have a buffer with enought space, then look at strcat documentation.